# Django CyclicDependencyError in model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to perform a `makemigrations`, but it errors out like this:

> django.utils.topological_sort.CyclicDependencyError: Cyclic dependency
> in graph: (<CreateModel  name='CasprAdminStatusDef',
> fields=[('assessment_type',
> <django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField>), ('status_name',
> <django.db.models.fields.CharField>)], options={'db_table':
> 'CAsPr_Admin_Status_Def', 'managed': False}, bases=(<class
> 'django.db.models.base.Model'>,), managers=[]>, {<CreateModel
> name='CasprAdminStatusDef', fields=[('assessment_type',
> <django.db.models.fields.related.OneToOneField>), ('status_name',
> <django.db.models.fields.CharField>)], options={'db_table':
> 'CAsPr_Admin_Status_Def', 'managed': False}, bases=(<class
> 'django.db.models.base.Model'>,), managers=[]>})

The model that is erroring out is very simple. I don't see the problem:

```
class CasprAdminStatusDef(models.Model):
    assessment_type = models.OneToOneField('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Assessment_Type', primary_key=True, related_name='+')  # Field name made lowercase.
    statusid = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='StatusID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    status_name = models.CharField(db_column='Status_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CAsPr_Admin_Status_Def'
        unique_together = (('assessment_type', 'statusid'),)
```

This model was created by `inspectdb`. What's going on here?

Comment: What is the model supposed to do? Off the bat there's an `assessment_type` field that's the primary key, and also a OneToOne to the same model ('self'), which I'm not sure can work. `statusid` is also a Foreign Key, to itself again, and the names do not suggest a hierarchy. `inspectdb` does its best to "guess" the definition based on the db but it should always be rechecked. If all is correct, you *could* try migrating first without Foreign/OneToOne fields first, and adding them later -- except `managed=False` means Django won't create the table, among other things.

Comment: The model is part of something much bigger. This is a legacy database, hence the `managed=False`. I figured out that I had a weird self-referencing foreign key in the table structure. I didn't create the tables but once I removed that FK a re-scan of the database gave me a proper model.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I had some weird self-referencing CONSTRAINT in the table definition. That created this weird model.

I removed the CONSTRAINT, updated the model and the problem went away:

```
class CasprAdminStatusDef(models.Model):
    assessment_type = models.CharField(db_column='Assessment_Type', max_length=5, primary_key=True)
    statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column='StatusID')
    status_name = models.CharField(db_column='Status_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'CAsPr_Admin_Status_Def'
        unique_together = (('assessment_type', 'statusid'),)
```